# How can I build a search engine for a knowledge base system?

Tags: c#, .net, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I need to build full-text search functionality into our knowledge base system using C#. How do I start?

Comment: WTF is up with the flipping back and forth?

Answer (score 2):

For example from Lucene:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/

C# port is here http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

You should also read something about the the information retrieval, and you can start with this one : [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Information-Retrieval-Ricardo-Baeza-Yates/dp/020139829X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020139829X)

Answer (score 2):

I use Lucene.Net in my open source [bug tracking](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) application, BugTracker.NET.   Download it and look at my_lucene.cs - which does the indexing - and search_text.aspx - which does the searching.  I went from knowing nothing about Lucene to being able to integrate it into my app in just a weekend.

I explain it here:
http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need an indexing facility if your text base is non trivial.